# How can I set the number of clients on my WiFi using CMD/BAT/VBS?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, wifi, netsh

Is it possible to set the number of clients using the CMD - **netsh** command or any other command. Also if it is possible by using VBScript.
I want to change the number of clients according to my needs.

When I type the following code:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

It shows the Maximum number of clients that I can connect to, I want to change the total number of clients I want to connect according to my requirement so that no one else can connect.

Comment: Can you go more into detail?

Comment: Are you trying to make changes on a hotspot made from your computer? or a router that is seperate from your computer?

Comment: I am trying to make changes on the hotspot from the computer. I know it is possible to do it but I am unable to find any code that works.